# ffmpeg Map with multiple input files

Tags: audio, video, encoding, ffmpeg, media

I have two files. One with a single video stream  and another with one audio stream and one subtitle stream.

How can I merge these two files together?

I tried using the command

```
ffmpeg -y \
    -i "video.mkv" \
    -i audioandsubtitles.mkv \
    -c copy \
    ~/Downloads/output.mkv"
```

but it only copied the audio and video stream, not the subtitle stream.

How can I make it merge all three?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y \
    -i "video.mkv" \
    -i audioandsubtitles.mkv \
    -map 0:v -map 1 -c copy \
    ~/Downloads/output.mkv"
```

Comment: Can you expand on what -map does?

Comment: here is a link that shows how to use map: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map